# Post date on Custom field

Tags: functions, custom-field

I want to use 2 custom fields.
One is YEAR field
Another is Month field.

automatically these will be filled with post date when I post my blog.
How can I do it ?

Comment: What have you already tried to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hook called save_posts

so you need to hook a function into that post like

```
add_action('save_posts','store_date');
function store_date(){
  if(get_post_type()=='post'){
   $month=get_the_date('M');
   $year=get_the_date('Y');
   update_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'month-field',$month);
   update_post_meta(get_The_ID(),'year-field',$year);
 }
}
```

This should be all you need

Here are additonal links to [save_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) and [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)